# A permutation of the integer numbers on which the algorithm runs forever

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have the following problem in my university:

What is the minimum *n* that there is a permutation of the integer numbers from *0* to *n - 1*, on which the algorithm runs forever?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(0);
    v.push_back(6);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(7);
    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(4);
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if(v[i] > i) 
        {
            j = i;
            while( j < v.size() && v[j] >= j )
            {
                j = j + 1;
            }
            int temp = v[i];
            v[i] = v[j];
            v[j] = temp;
            i = 0;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've found the permulation {3, 1, 0, 6, 2, 7, 5,4} manually. I will be thankfull if somebody check my answer or find smaller permulation.

I've tried a lot of permulations, but not by brute force, but by the logical choosing, and I think that is the smallest sequence in which the algorithm loops.

Comment: On which *what* algorithm runs forever? This one? Is it correctly coded in Java? What's the specification?

Comment: Yes, this algorithm. But the values of vector are mine. I need to find vector of the smallest size which makes algorithm run forever.

Comment: Sorry, that I tagged it by "Java". Initially the algorithm was on pseudocode.

Comment: The program runs and exits successfully: http://ideone.com/Jj1WL0

Comment: Sorry again. I've edit my permulation.

Comment: You can brute force and find that n = 6. Then you can print out the result per loop to see what is the cause of the problem, then go back on the reasoning.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of lecture has such exercises?

Comment: To tell the truth, I ve took this problem from classmate at the univesity. I dont know where he has found it. This problem seemed to me rather intersting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum n is 6.
Possible solutions:

0 3 4 5 2 1 
leads to
0 2 4 5 3 1 
leads back to
0 3 4 5 2 1

Comment: Yes, I ve checked. It is infinite loop. Thank you!